# Pytest-playwright deletes output folder

Tags: pytest, playwright-python

For some reason the `pytest` or `pytest --output "foldername"` deletes the folder where it was supposed to store output. Did not find any information about this behavior whatsoever

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.